# Center elements inside Tailwind Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, grid, tailwind-css

my problem is center elements with Tailwind Grid.
GroupTooltipIcon1/GroupTooltipIcon2 are component that contain an svg.
I have to be able to center the svg component within this grid tailwind, can you help me?

```
<div className="mt-[75px] grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 justify-items-center">
<div>
  <div className="iconInsideTooltip">
    <GroupTooltipIcon1 width="48px" height="48px" />
  </div>
  <TextSection
    p5={
      <>
        <div>
            Testo 1
        </div>
      </>
    }
  />
</div>   
</div>

  const GroupTooltipIcon1 = ({
      width = "48",
      height = "48",
      classes = "stroke-white",
    }) => {
      return (
        <svg
          className={classes}
          style={{ width, height }}
          viewBox={`0 0 48 48`}
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
        <g clip-path="url(#clip0_206_1350)">
        <path d="M31.6027 22.5623L34.1509 20.0644C38.9389 22.0715 42.8398 19.6492 42.8398 19.6492C48.6345 14.1502 46.9798 6.58116 46.9798 6.58116L40.1784 13.3197C40.1784 13.3197 37.9889 13.3197 36.2775 11.8977C34.8555 10.1801 34.8555 7.99681 34.8555 7.99681L41.6003 1.20169C41.6003 1.20169 34.0313 -0.453049 28.5323 5.34168C28.5323 5.34168 26.11 9.24259 28.117 14.0306L23.373 18.869" 
            stroke="white" 
            strokeLinecap="round" 
            strokeLinejoin="round"/>                   
        </g>
        <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip0_206_1350">
        <rect width="48" height="48" fill="white"/>
        </clipPath>
        </defs>
        </svg>
      );
    };
    
  
    export default React.memo(GroupTooltipIcon1);
```

I have to be able to center the svg component within this grid tailwind, can you help me?
Thank you for help

Comment: Please provide us with a [minmal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you better.

Comment: You are already centering your grid items in their respective column by using `justify-items-center`. You can see a working example here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/7tA1631xft

Comment: The problem is center the svg inside this grid

Comment: Please provide more information and a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can really help you.

Comment: Ok i add svg component. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by doing it this way. I hope it will be useful to someone

```
<div className="mt-[75px] grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 items-start">
<div>
  <div className="iconInsideTooltip flex justify-center">
    <GroupTooltipIcon1 width="48px" height="48px" />
  </div>
  <TextSection
    customClasses={{ "text-center p-5": "p5" }}
    p5={
      <>
        <div>
            Testo 1
        </div>
      </>
    }
  />
</div>
</div>
```